# need some advice on comboboxes in c# without using databases

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am new to VS2013 and c# and am trying to build a basic templating program using windows forms.

What I am trying to accomplish is having a combobox with a list of products populate a second combobox with acceptable versions for that product.

So if i pick productA from the list i get versions 1, 2 and 3 as options and if I pick productB i get version 2.1,2.2 and 2.3 as options.

I am ok with building both lists out as there isnt many products or versions but i do not want to use a database connection as i want this to be a portable tool.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this would be great!

Comment: Please make sure you understand the difference between a combobox and listbox.

Comment: Theres no indication here of what you have tried.

Comment: It is called "cascading comboboxes"... Please clarify how DB is involved into your question - there is no reason why you have to populate choices from DB...

Comment: I did mention i was brand new to this. I don't even know the right questions to ask yet but i'm sure i will learn. There is no indication of what i did because i don't know what to try yet.

Comment: As for the database comment, i googled a lot on what i wanted to do and all the solutions came up with using a  datasource and the options ive seen for this all point back to some sort of database. I figured there has to be a way to build this in c# since i figure it would be pretty simple concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is:

```
comboBox2.Items.Clear();
switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) {
    case "ProductA":
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"1", "2", "3"});
        break;
    case "ProductB":
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"2.1", "2.2", "2.3"});
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use classes.  This allows you override the ToString method and employ the datasource property of the comboxes:

The classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public class Version
    {
        public double vers = 0;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return vers.ToString();
        }
    }
    public string name = "";
    public List<Version> versions = new List<Version>();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Build the a list of `Product` and populate one combobox:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product{name = "ProductA",versions = new List<Product.Version>()
    {
        new Product.Version{vers = 1},
        new Product.Version{vers = 2},
        new Product.Version{vers = 3}
    }},
    new Product{name = "ProductB",versions = new List<Product.Version>()
    {
        new Product.Version{vers = 2.1},
        new Product.Version{vers = 2.2},
        new Product.Version{vers = 2.3}
    }}                
};
comboBox2.DataSource = products;
```

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to populate the second combobox with the list of versions for the product selected in the first one:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product selectedproduct = (Product)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
    comboBox3.DataSource = selectedproduct.versions;
}
```